# Index confusion in Tu's treatment of Taylor's Theorem with remainder in "An Introduction to Manifolds"

Tags: differential-geometry, taylor-expansion

In Tu's book, specifically the section on "Taylor's Theorem with remainder", there appears to be a changing of the meaning of some subscripts which isn't noted. The theorem states that if $f$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function in an open, star-shaped subset, $U$, of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (w.r.t. a point $p=(p^1,\ldots,p^n)$ in the subset), then there are functions $g_1(x), \ldots , g_n(x) \in C^{\infty}(U)$ such that 
$$
f(x) = f(p) + \sum_{i=1}^n{(x^i - p^i)g_i(x)}, \,\,\,\,\, g_i(p)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p).
$$
This seems straightforward, as the indices go from $1$ to the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$, however later on he fixes $n=1, p=0$ and repeatedly applies the lemma to obtain
\begin{equation}
g_i(x) = g_i(0) + xg_{i+1}(x)
\end{equation} and then uses this fact to expand out an arbitrary $f \in C^{\infty}$ to an approximation of its Taylor series about the point $0$. Here is where I become confused, as didn't we have $1 \leq i \leq n$ in the statement of the theorem? It seems to me that the $g_i$ take on a different meaning at this point, and the $i$ is used as a kind of placeholder saying how many of these terms we've used in our approximation.
Also, it seems worth noting that later on (in an exercise) double indices are given to the $g_i$ as in this case we have taken $n = 2$. If my above assumption that the $i$ are taking on a different meaning then I believe I understand the theorem, however if there is some connection between the two usages of the indices, then I am confused.

Comment: also confused notation in the book
[just the chain rule using show similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763506/question-regarding-proof-of-taylor-remainder-theorem-in-tus-an-introduction-to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two $g_i$s are different. Right after he finishes the proof, he says in one dimension from the lemma
$$f(x) = f(0) + xg_1(x)$$
Here, $g_1(x)$ is given as you have it above by the partial derivative $g_1(x)=\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$. However, let's forget that and just call it $g_1(x)$, which is what he does (he says *"for some function $g_1(x)$"*). Now let's apply the lemma to to this $g_1(x)$, well there exists some function which we will call $g_2(x)$ such that:
$$g_1(x)=g_1(0)+xg_2(x)$$
In this case by the lemma $g_2(x)=\frac{\partial g_1(x)}{\partial x}$, but again we are forgetting this and just leaving the functions implicit.