# Question Regarding Proof of Taylor Remainder Theorem in Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, taylor-expansion

The statement:

Let $f$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function on an open set $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ which is star shaped with respect to a point $p=(p^1,...,p^n) \in U$. Then there are functions $g_1(x),...,g_n(x)\in C^{\infty} $ such that

$$f(x)=f(p)+\sum_{i=1}^n(x^i-p^i)g_i(x)$$, where $g_i(p)=\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x^i}}(p)$.

The proof of the statement follows from the fact that since $U$ is star shaped, the line segment between $p$ and any point $x\in U$ is contained in $U$. Therefore for $0\leq t\leq 1$, $f(p+t(x-p))$ is defined.

This upcoming portion is where I don't understand his application of the chain rule, and would appreciate some clarification.

"By the chain rule

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}f(p+t(x-p))=\sum (x^i-p^i)\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x^i}}(p+t(x-p))$$ "

From my understanding, the left hand side of the equality would come from the chain rule when $f$ is a function of $x=(x^1,...,x^n)$, and each $x^i$ is a function of $t$. But in this instance each $x^i$ is not a function of $t$ as they are both used in the same equation to describe a line segment, so why can the chain rule be applied in this instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from using $x$ in two different ways.

I will use $x = (x^1,.., x^n)$ as coordinates on $U$.  Let $y = (y^1,...,y^n)$ be any particular point in $U$.

Consider the curve $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow U$ with $\gamma(t) = p + t(y-p)$.  In terms of the $x^i$ coordinates, we have $x^i(t) = p^i + t(y^i - p^i)$.

Now, consider the composition $f\circ \gamma$.  By the chain rule, $$\frac{d}{dt} (f(\gamma(t)) = \sum_i \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\right|_{\gamma(t)} \frac{ dx^i}{dt}.$$

But $\frac{dx^i}{dt} = y^i - p^i$.  Substituting this in gives the formula you wrote.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.